# Is it okay to mark as 'a duplicate' with an unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, flags

I am just wondering about the purpose of marking as "a duplicate" flag.

In my opinion, "a duplicate" flag is not only needed to avoid asking similar questions but also to provide proper solutions to the asker.

Then, is it okay to mark as "a duplicate" with an unanswered question?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to do that is a) on meta, or b) if both questions are from the same OP

Comment: Or if you get a diamond moderator involved, @Patrice. Request that with a flag. Be sure to be very clear about why you're asking a moderator to do it (i.e., why you can't do it yourself), and make sure the questions are exact duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the only case when such an action is not blocked on SO is when the question is by the same author and in most cases such a duplicate is used for identical reposts (i.e. if the OP tried to shake downvotes that way).

The site logic enforces the following rules for closing as a duplicate: the target must be by the same author *or* the target must have an answer (upvoted or accepted post). The exact rules and reasoning, including "meta does not enforce 'have an answer' rule" is on the main meta - [Changes to “close as duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux)